# What mean copy in ObservableCollection<T>(List<T>) documentation

Tags: c#, list, memory

I have 2 containers as:

```
List<T>
ObservableCollection<T>
```

I construct the `ObservableCollection<T>` containers with a filtred part of `List<T>`. I took a look the documentation of the constructor: `ObservableCollection<T>(List<T>)` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-collections-objectmodel-observablecollection-1-ctor(system-collections-generic-list((-0)))).
In this docummentation this is write:

> Initializes a new instance of the ObservableCollection class that contains elements copied from the specified list.

But I don't know if the word `copied` mean real memory copy or referencing the value of item in the `List<T>` into the `ObservableCollection<T>` ?

Comment: That depends of what T is. For a valuetype you get a copy. For a referencetype you still reference the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment @Ralf:

> That depends of what T is. For a valuetype you get a copy. For a referencetype you still reference the same object.

More info about [ReferenceType](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) and [ValueType](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.valuetype?view=net-6.0)